# How to plot multiple time series data based on a specific 'category' type ei: Disaster type == Flood

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created the following df which contains the number of times a specific type of disaster occurred in a given year, and I want to create a graph with multiple lines depicting the changes over time, of the number of each disaster happened per year. Therefore, each disaster type would have it's own line, and one would be able to see for example, are winter storms decreasing while droughts increasing?

Currently, I've attempted to define the X and y, however, I'm not sure how to groupby flood and still add the number per year over time. For some reason, when this is run, I'm getting a keyerror: 'Start_year' -- which could possibly be because the start year was used as an index, but I've reset it as seen below, which should have taken care of that. Sorry a bit new with this.

```
#Number of each type of disaster each year
df_yearly_tcount = df_time.groupby(['Start_year', 'Disaster_Type']).size()

yearly_tcount=pd.DataFrame(df_yearly_tcount)
yearly_tcount.reset_index()

X = yearly_tcount['Start_year']
y = yearly_tcount(['Disaster_type']=='Flood')

plt.plot(X, y, label = 'Flood')
```

Entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 


from scipy.stats import zscore

#Import Datased
df = pd.read_csv('database.csv')

df_time = (df[['County','Disaster Type','Start Date', 'End Date']][0: :])

#Preprocessing      
     
#Number of NaN values          
df_nan = df[['County','Disaster Type','Start Date', 'End Date']].isna().sum()

#NaN values as a percentage as total 
df_nan_number = [(df_nan.sum(axis=0)), str((((539/45330)*100))) +'%']

#Remove NaN values
df_time.dropna(subset = ["County", 'End Date'], inplace=True)

#Set Date Format
df_time['Start_Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df_time['End_Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

#Create new column == Disaster Length
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = (df_time.Start_Date_A - df_time.End_Date_A).dt.days

#Create new column == start year
df_time['Start_year'] = df_time['Start_Date_A'].dt.year

#Dropped  Old Date Formats from df
df_time = df_time.drop(columns=['Start Date', 'End Date'], axis=1)

#Replace 0 day values with 1 to indicate a Disaster length of 1 Day
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = df_time['Disaster_Length'].replace({0:1})

#Replace all values with absolute values so all days are represented as positive numeric values
df_time['Disaster_Length'] = df_time['Disaster_Length'].abs()


# Locating man-made and non 'natural' disasters, sorting Disaster types, and analyzing value counts
df_DTypes= df_time['Disaster Type'].values

df_DTypes=pd.DataFrame(df_DTypes)

df_DType_VCounts=(df_DTypes.value_counts()).sort_values(ascending=True)

df_DType_Natural=(df_DType_VCounts.drop(['Human Cause', 'Chemical', 'Dam/Levee Break', 'Terrorism','Other'],axis=0)).sort_values(ascending=True)

df_time = df_time.rename(columns={'Disaster Type': 'Disaster_Type'})

#Removing non-natural disasters from main df_time
df_time = df_time[(df_time.Disaster_Type != 'Human Cause') & (df_time.Disaster_Type != 'Chemical') & (df_time.Disaster_Type != 'Dam/Levee Break') & (df_time.Disaster_Type != 'Terrorism') & (df_time.Disaster_Type != 'Other') ]

#Resetting index for final df Analysis 
df_time.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)

#Analysis 

#Dataframe with mean disaster length for each year
df_yearly_mean_len = df_time.groupby(['Start_year']).mean()

df_yearly_mean_len.reset_index().plot('Start_year','Disaster_Length')


#Number of disasters declared per year
yearly_dcount = df_time.groupby(['Start_year']).size()


yearly_dcount=pd.DataFrame(yearly_dcount)
yearly_dcount.columns=['Number_of_Disasters']



#Visualizing change in total number of disasters over time 
yearly_dcount.reset_index().plot('Start_year','Number_of_Disasters')


#Number of each type of disaster each year
df_yearly_tcount = df_time.groupby(['Start_year', 'Disaster_Type']).size()

yearly_tcount=pd.DataFrame(df_yearly_tcount)
yearly_tcount.reset_index()

X = yearly_tcount['Start_year']
y = yearly_tcount(['Disaster_type']=='Flood')

plt.plot(X, y, label = 'Flood')
```

Df

```
                            0
Start_year Disaster_Type     
1959       Flood            1
1964       Flood          115
1965       Drought         51
           Earthquake       6
           Flood          198
           Hurricane       56
           Storm            6
           Tornado        112
1966       Flood          113
           Tornado          2
           Typhoon          5
1967       Fire            10
           Flood          121
           Hurricane       29
           Tornado         36
           Typhoon          1
1968       Flood           76
           Hurricane       14
           Ice             21
           Tornado         50
           Typhoon          1
1969       Flood          394
           Hurricane       64
           Storm            1
           Tornado         46
1970       Fire             6
           Flood          180
           Hurricane        7
           Storm           17
           Tornado         11
```

Original Data set
https://www.kaggle.com/fema/federal-disasters

Comment: for your problem with Start_year missing, it is because reset_index is not inplace, so you need to reassign `yearly_tcount = yearly_tcount.reset_index()`

Comment: What's the specific data set you're working with? The FEMA disaster declarations?

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T, I had something similar but forgot the level param. Cheers

Comment: And @ifly6 -- no it's this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/fema/federal-disasters -- just looked at the kaggle one, I think it's a version of this, quite similar.

Comment: also, try to do `df_time.groupby(['Start_year', 'Disaster_Type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plot()`, it looks like you are after this plot with all disasters on same graph :)

Comment: Ouu that's nifty @Ben.T thanks. I was getting close, but you simplified it a lot. I looked up the docs for the unstack, and see that it alters how the data is placed, but I'm not sure in this case, what it's doing, if you could shed a little light that'd be great. thanks

Comment: globally `unstack` get all unique value of index, in this case the last one aka Dysaster_type as we did not specify any so default behavior, and create a column for each dystaster, populated by the value in the result of the `groupby.size`. then using `plot` on this reshaped dataframe create a line by column so per dysaster :) it is a bit like if you did a `pivot_table` with index the year and column the disaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on the right track. A lot of your code/styles seem to be trending in the correct direction. I put your data into a CSV and reset the multi-index. After this it is fairly simple to plot your data. It may look better with more data, but currently there are multiple outliers and disasters with missing data (1959 and 1964 for example). Furthermore, if you use a line graph, then you're comparing to the same y axis which could make it difficult to compare low and high frequency disasters (ex. earthquakes vs floods). You could alternatively plot the percent change, but this doesn't look very good either with the data provided. Lastly, you could use a stacked bar graph instead. Personally, I think this looks the best. How you chose to present your data depends on the goals of your chart, how quantitative or qualitative your want to be, and if you want to show raw data such as with a scatter plot. Regardless, here are some graphs and some code that should help.

[image]

```
types = ['Flood', 'Drought', 'Earthquake', 'Hurricane', 'Storm', 'Tornado',
       'Typhoon', 'Fire', 'Ice']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(16,14))
axes = axes.flatten()

ax = axes[0]
for i in range(len(types)):
    disaster_df = df[df.Disaster_Type == types[i]]
    ax.plot(disaster_df.Start_year, disaster_df.Size, linewidth=2.5, label=types[i])
ax.legend(ncol=3, edgecolor='w')
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
ax.set_title('Disasters Raw', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')

#remove 1959
ax = axes[1]
df2 = df.iloc[1:]

for i in range(len(types)):
    disaster_df = df2[df2.Disaster_Type == types[i]]
    ax.plot(disaster_df.Start_year, disaster_df.Size, linewidth=2.5, label=types[i])
ax.legend(ncol=3, edgecolor='w')
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
ax.set_title('Remove 1959', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')

#remove 1964
ax = axes[2]
df2 = df.iloc[2:]
for i in range(len(types)):
    disaster_df = df2[df2.Disaster_Type == types[i]]
    ax.plot(disaster_df.Start_year, disaster_df.Size, linewidth=2.5, label=types[i])
ax.legend(ncol=3, edgecolor='w')
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
ax.set_title('Remove 1959 and 1964', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')

#plot percent change
ax = axes[3]
df2 = df.iloc[2:]
for i in range(len(types)):
    disaster_df = df2[df2.Disaster_Type == types[i]]
    ax.plot(disaster_df.Start_year, disaster_df.Size.pct_change(), linewidth=2.5, label=types[i])
ax.legend(ncol=1, edgecolor='w', loc=(1, 0.5))
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right']]
ax.set_title('Try plotting percent change', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
df.pivot(index='Start_year', columns = 'Disaster_Type', values='Size' ).plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, zorder=3)
ax.legend(ncol=3, edgecolor='w')
[ax.spines[s].set_visible(False) for s in ['top','right', 'left']]
ax.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, bottom=False)

ax.grid(axis='y', dashes=(8,3), color='gray', alpha=0.3)
```

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic thanks! I'm learning a lot by going over your code, and it definitely points me in the right direction. And I agree, the stacked bar graph is much cleaner. I will take out those with missing data and try it with the full dataset. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the stacked bar example, how I can I be more selective, and utilize the type list, to for example, instead of having all Disaster types, be able to select particular ones, if I wanted to compare drought to flood for instance. Thanks!

Comment: selection = [ list of disasters to compare ]

df2 = df.pivot(index='Start_year', columns='Disaster_Type, values='Size')

df2[selection].plot.bar() 

OR

df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)